# optimization scheme of numpy.einsum

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

What is the optimization scheme of numpy.einsum ? Does it optimize the memory consumption or the CPU or anything else ?

I don't see this discussed anywhere. Maybe it's related to the different ‘optimize’ options, that I don't understand

Comment: Personally my experience and experience of my group mates says "Never to use np.einsum, because it is too slow. Just use element-wise operations and multiplication of matrices."

Comment: Mostly it has to do with evaluation order when using 3 or more variables and complex combinations of indices.  Look at `einsum_path` docs.

Comment: Give a sample of the kinds of calculations you are using it for.

Comment: In general `np.einsum` is faster than element-wise operations for simple operations. Use `optimize=True` if you have GEMM's.